# cant Getting Variable value in parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i am not getting value of variable rsp2  in select statement parameter.

```
 DECLARE @RSP  varchar(50)
  DECLARE @RSP2 varchar(50)
 SET @RSP =  '(<DL>,<DM>)'
SELECT @RSP  
 SET @RSP2 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@RSP,'(',''),')',''),'<',''''),'>','''')
SELECT @RSP2 
    SELECT [F_YEAR] FROM tbl1 WHERE 
                 RSP  IN (@RSP2)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Sorry, it's not clear to me from your question

Comment: why do you feel so ? i executed the same query till "Select @RSP2" I got the result 'DL','DM'

Comment: I think he is saying that when he executes the final SQL statement no results are returned.

Comment: It's a common error in SQL, but I've never understood why. Do you not see that a single string that happens to *contain* commas is, logically, different from *several* strings *separated* by commas?

Answer (score 1):

I *assume* that you want to get the value of `f_year` to be assigned to the `@rsp` variable.

```
DECLARE @RSP  varchar(50)
      , @RSP2 varchar(50);

 SET @RSP = '(<DL>,<DM>)';
 SET @RSP2 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@RSP,'(',''),')',''),'<',''''),'>','''');

SET @RSP = (
  SELECT Max(f_year)
  FROM   tbl1
  WHERE  RSP  = @RSP2;
);

SELECT @RSP  As rsp
     , @RSP2 As rsp2;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
DECLARE @RSP  varchar(50)
DECLARE @RSP2 varchar(50)
SET @RSP =  '(<DL>,<DM>)'
SELECT @RSP  
SET @RSP2 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@RSP,'(',''),')',''),'<',''''),'>','''')
SELECT @RSP2 
EXEC('SELECT [F_YEAR] FROM tbl1 WHERE 
             RSP  IN ('+@RSP2+')')
```

Hope this will help you

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @RSP  varchar(50) = '(<DL>,<DM>)'
DECLARE @RSP2 varchar(50)
-- next line has been changed as well
SET @RSP2 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@RSP,'(',''),')',''),'<',''),'>','')
SELECT @RSP RSP, @RSP2 RSP2 

SELECT [F_YEAR] FROM tbl1 
WHERE RSP in (
SELECT t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)')
FROM (
SELECT x = CAST('<t>' + 
    REPLACE(@RSP2, ',', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
) a
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c))
```